# integrating jsx and erb in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I read that erb could be used with jsx in a reactjs component, so I figured I'd try using the component to render db objects.

Here's the component:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <% @items.each do |item| %>
        <div class="four wide column">
          <div class="card">
            <%= link_to item do %>
              <div class="item-image">
                <%= image_tag item.image.url(:thumb) %>
              </div>
              <div class="item-info">
                <h1><%= item.title %></h1>
                <span>$<%= item.price %></span>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @items = Item.all
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: @items.to_json}
        end
    end
end
```

This gives an error `"syntax error, unexpected ')'`

The jsx renders if I strip out the model loop, object properties, and link_to, but obviously the data that I want to show is missing.

And is this a bad way of doing it? Seems to me like this should be in the views directory - not assets/javascript/components.

Comment: What is the file name of your Reactjs componenet? Where did you put it?

Comment: It's in the assets/javascript/components directory.

Comment: And what is the file name? What is the full file name with "all" the extensions?

Comment: File name is `item.jsx.erb`

Comment: Is your file named item.js.jsx.erb

This works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If Rails can't render `jsx.erb` or `js.erb` files

1. Go to the **webpack configuration** file `config/webpacker.yml`
2. **Manually add the extensions** you need; `jsx.erb` or `js.erb`...etc

```
   extensions:
    - .jsx.erb
    - .js.erb
    - .jsx
```

Never Give Up!

Comment: I think I got it figured out way back when I asked this, but didn't post the answer. I don't remember what I did, but I like your energy!!!